# Back button doesnt work in ios 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I'm using this code in all ViewControllers to create back button:

```
self.btnBack = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 44)];
[self.btnBack setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(cancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)cancel:(id)sender 
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];   
}
```

But when I go to controller with `UIWebView` I need top tap 2 times to go back in ios 6.
And in ios 7 when I tap 1 time `UIWebView` disappeared show black screen with my navigation and on 2nd tap app crashes.

In all screen this works great maybe something special with `UIWebView`, I dont know.
Help please!

I push webview:

```
-(IBAction)doPrivacy:(id)sender 
{
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    WebPageViewController *web = (WebPageViewController*)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebPage"];

    web.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    web.urlToOpen = @"http://dfdfdf.co";

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:web animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Could you show how you're pushing the UIWebView in?

Comment: Its pretty odd, seems like you're doing the right thing. If you're doing storyboards can you try using the storyboard segue linking and setting the URL/hidesBottomBarWhenPushed using -prepareForSegue:

Comment: When I'm trying to use prepare app crashes with SIGABRT. I'm doing this:- (IBAction)doPrivacy:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Privacy" sender:self];}  
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Privacy"]){
        WebPageViewController *web = (WebPageViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        web.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
        web.urlToOpen = @"http://ddfdf.com";
    }
}

Comment: Could you show what the viewcontroller with the webview looks like?

Comment: Here is links of top and bottom of my ViewController with UIWebView [top](http://cs413720.vk.me/v413720572/437c/e4bDCDbQI-g.jpg)  [bottom](http://cs413720.vk.me/v413720572/4374/l0lX2d-C-f8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm calling the same segue twice, you can fix this by unlinking the connection from the CELL DIRECTLY, to your segue, and having the segue connection originate at the top of the table hierarchy in IB, rather than nested inside the cell. Connect the segue from you View Controller itself, to the segue. If you have done this correct, when you select the segue, it should highlight the ENTIRE view it is coming from, not just the cell.